# How to deploy a web part that uses AjaxControlToolkit with WSPBuilder?

Tags: wspbuilder, solution-package, web-part, ajax-control-tookit

I'm trying to deploy a webpart that is an ASP.NET user control that uses AjaxControlToolkit via WSPBuilder, with not much success.

There seems to be a lot of web.config edits that need to be done in order to get this working, and I'd prefer if this is done automatically.

Does anyone have a tutorial that I can use? Or a .zip file with the WSPBuilder solution as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u check http://features.codeplex.com/ , there is a feature Ajax.Config Feature which will update the web.config file for necessary entries. I am not too sure of the AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: thank you, I've used the code from that feature to make my own modifications!